# How to reduce dimensions of new data/input after applying dimensionality reduction method like MCA

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I have a categorical training set like this

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
 9      8      10     9
10      8       9     9
.....................
```

and after i reduced the dimensions by applying MCA(Multiple Correspondance Analysis) on it, i got something like this

```
dim1    dim2
0.857  -0.575
0.654   0.938
.............
```

Now my question is how to find the (dim1, dim2) of a new data like this as input ?

```
col1  col2   col3  col4
10     9       8     8
```

the outputs of MCA after performing on the training set is eigenvalues, inertia etc

My code in python:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import prince
data = pd.read_csv("data/training set.csv")
X = data.loc[:, 'OS.1':'DSA.1']
size = len(X)
X = X.values.tolist()

#...
#data preprocessing
#...

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
mca = prince.MCA(
               n_components=2,
               n_iter=3,
               copy=True,
               check_input=True,
               engine='auto',
               random_state=42
                )

mca = mca.fit(df)
X = mca.transform(df)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(X)
```

1.I want to take an input from user
2.Preprocess it before performing dimensional reduction using MCA
3.predict it's cluster using K means

Comment: Please share your relevant *code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep your MCA object `mca` alive to be able to use it to just transform new input data. To do that, just call the `transform method on your new data`

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import prince
data = pd.read_csv("data/training set.csv")
X = data.loc[:, 'OS.1':'DSA.1']
size = len(X)
X = X.values.tolist()

#...
#data preprocessing
#...

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
mca = prince.MCA(
               n_components=2,
               n_iter=3,
               copy=True,
               check_input=True,
               engine='auto',
               random_state=42
                )

mca = mca.fit(df)
X = mca.transform(df)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(X)

# New data into x_new
# 1. Preprocess x_new as you preprocessed x
# Reuse mca on x_new
df_new = pd.DataFrame(x_new)
X_new = mca.transform(df_new)

# predictions
km.predict(X_new)
```